# Testing Django Apps On Heroku With Cypress

Tags: django, testing, heroku, integration-testing, cypress

I'm a hobby web developer looking to build my first product with the django web framework which I will host on Heroku.  Cypress looks like a great modern tool for UI testing which I certainly want to use.  In local development I am using it within django testing so that the django staticliveservertestcase runs first - which creates a separate development server process, and a test database, if one hasn't been created already.  Within this test I then call a bash script which executes a cypress UI test.  See the example below.

**Bash Script -**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 # the 1st command line argument
echo $2 # the 2nd command line argument

./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --env baseUrl=$1 --spec $2
```

**Django Test Code -**

```
class ExampleTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def test_view_url(self):
        from subprocess import run
        exit_code = run([
            './cypress/run.sh',
            f'http://{self.server_thread.host}:{self.server_thread.port}',
            'cypress/integration/sample_spec.js'
        ])
        self.assertEqual(0, exit_code.returncode)
```

From my understanding this is the opposite to the standard cypress approach.  Normally cypress runs outside of the app independently and simply runs through all the tests which interact with the app.  Here the cypress tests are called by the django process.  Unless I am mistaken there are obvious advantages to this approach.  I can test the UI and whether objects where created in the database after the UI test has run.

Is it possible, and if this how, to do this within Heroku?  So Heroku would simply call the test script -

```
python manage.py test
```

And I get UI testing and unit testing all done in one go.  It would also be nice to see the tests running in interactive mode.  Which may be a challenge because Heroku obviously runs everything in a linux container - I don't plan on using Docker incidentally because I think that limits a lot of the features Heroku offers.

Comment: I like this approach but do you not take a performance hit by spinning up a new cypress instance per test (vs having an instance running)